# Merge two table where the second tables rows are not referenced in the first table

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I'm re-posting a more clear version of a previous question I deleted.

As the example below shows, I want to combine `table_b` into `table_a` only if `table_b`'s id doesn't appear in `table_a`'s `table_b_id` column. Each table should have a null value for any fields it doesn't have.

Example:

**table_a**

```
+----+-------+------------+
| id | name  | table_b_id |
+----+-------+------------+
| 0  | mike  | 1          |
+----+-------+------------+
| 1  | jack  | 1          |
+----+-------+------------+
```

**table_b**

```
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
| 0  | tom   |
+----+-------+
| 1  | joe   |
+----+-------+
```

**Result:**

```
+-------------+-------+------------+
| original_id | name  | table_b_id |
+-------------+-------+------------+
| 0           | mike  | 1          |
+-------------+-------+------------+
| 0           | tom   |            |
+-------------+-------+------------+
| 1           | jack  | 1          |
+-------------+-------+------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question can almost directly be translated into a query. You want to see table **A** queried but supplemented with rows from **B** for which `id` of **B** is not in any `table_b_id` of **A**. So the following `UNION` combines **A** with the subset of **B** where `id` of **B** is not in `table_b_id`:

```
SELECT table_a.id AS original_id, table_a.name, table_a.table_b_id FROM table_a
UNION ALL
SELECT table_b.id AS original_id, table_b.name, NULL AS table_b_id FROM table_b
  WHERE table_b.id NOT IN (SELECT table_a.table_b_id FROM table_a)
```

Note that for the second set we select `NULL` as `table_b_id` because **A** does not have this field.